# How do you set different detail views in AgGrid depending on what column is expanded?

Tags: ag-grid

Looking to show different detail views depending on what column is expanded. Not 100% sure this is possible.

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/master-detail-other/#example-detail-scrolls-with-master
[image]

In the example above you can see that "Mia Smith" is expanded to show her call log. Is it possible to configure AgGrid so that a different detail grid is shown if the user clicks on the "Account" column? Eg. showing the spend for account 177001.